# Do all Java application servers support JNDI data sources?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, datasource, jndi, java-ee-6

Are some Java app servers **not** supporting JDBC data sources over JNDI ?

I know it's pretty common they do. But since it is not a Java EE standard, there is no guarantee they all actually do provide the support.

The reason I am asking is to investigate the feasibility of a system requirement for a generic web application we're making. It should be deployable on as many kinds of apps servers as possible.

Comment: I always thought that supporting JNDI and JNDI datasources ***is*** a _requirement_ for a JavaEE container (even for "just" a servlet container)

Comment: JNDI sits in the JVM (javax.naming). But the usage for data sources, mail sessions, etc... is not part of JEE. Well, not that I am aware of at least.

Comment: @JanGoyvaerts It most certainly is part of J2EE.

Comment: That's good news ! I'll look it up on JCP. You have a JSR number in mind by any chance ? :-) @a_horse_wth_no_name The question of course  is whether JEE does care about certain usages of the resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if an app server is Java EE complaint, then it supports looking up datasources using JNDI.

[Here is a link to all of the Java EE complaint app servers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html)

***Source:***
Section EE.15.19 of the Java EE7 spec, which describes the requirements for a Default Data Source.

> The Java EE Product Provider must make the default data source accessible to the application under the **JNDI** name java:comp/DefaultDataSource.

The spec also references using JNDI to lookup a datasource in numerous other places, section EE.15.19 was just the first one that came to mind for me.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, i use container managed things like the datasources to ensure that may application will be generic and deployable on as many application servers as possible.  A goal ofJava EE vendor portablility.

(I have consulting clients in the public sector where I use this to help them move between vendors and upgrade legacy systems, always works well for me.)

in JSR 316 / Java EE 6 spec for example discusses JNDI in many areas as well as JDBC in section EE.2.7.6 as well as JPA in section EE.2.7.7.

Datasources themselves are part of the Java SE.  If hypothetically an application server vendor did not include a resource adaptor for JDBC Datasources, they would still have to provide JPA and they still have to provide JCA hence such a resource adaptor could be added after market.

Once in the java EE early days i configured JMS by adding a resource adaptor because it wasn't installed by default.  but the vendor still provided it and the server wasn't actually Java EE licensed at the time.